# JUnit tests for Generic Links in tapestry

Tags: java, junit, junit4, tapestry

I have developed UI page which has href to external link. Now this external link is built (with db based key values for http request parameters) in a class which extends `GenericLink` of Tapestry. I am overriding `public ILink getLink(IRequestCycle cycle)` and `public String getHref()` methods for that. The developed task is working as expected.
Now I want to write JUnit tests for this class, but I read there is other [mechanism for Unit testing](https://tapestry.apache.org/unit-testing-pages-or-components.html) in Tapestry but this is again not clear to me w.r.t. GenericLinks.
Any leads to any artical will really help in order to test GenericLink class.

Comment: Looks like your project uses Tapestry 4, but you're linking to a documentation of the latest tapestry 5.x releases. I suggest you to look for Tapestry 4 examples, e.g. this may be a good start http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/tapestry-test/index.html

Comment: Yes I think, I referred some wrong ref. My project is based on Tapestry 4. But I dont see proper JUnit for that.

Comment: Have you checked any of these tests? http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tapestry/tapestry4/trunk/tapestry-framework/src/test/org/apache/tapestry/link/ they're for DirectLink not GenericLink, but maybe it's something similar?